# Check em Radio button com dados de BD

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, radiobutton

Estou tendo problemas ao pegar os dados do banco e passar via session para meu form, todos os dados inputados estão vindo corretamente, somente não consigo passa-los como `check` para os meus radios... testei de varias formas, umas delas foi:

```html
<div class='row'>
        <div class='col-lg-9'>
            <div class='radio'>
                <label for='fisica'>
                    <input type='radio' tabindex="1" class="tipo_pessoa" checked="checked" name='tipo_pessoa' id='fisica' value='fisica' />Pessoa Física</label>
            </div>
            <div class='radio'>
                <label for='juridica'>
                    <input type='radio' tabindex="2" class="tipo_pessoa" name='tipo_pessoa' id='juridica' value='juridica' />Pessoa Jurídica</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```html
<?
$value=$row['tipo_pessoa'];
 
$checked1=($value=="fisica")?'checked':'';
$checked2=($value=="juridica")?'checked':'';
?>
 
<input type="radio" name="tipo_pessoa" value="fisica" <?php echo $checked1; ?> />
Fisica

<input type="radio" name="tipo_pessoa" value="juridica" <?php echo $checked2; ?> />
Juridica
```

Answer (score 0):

**Apenas adicione o checked**

```
checked="<?php echo $checked1; ?>"
```

Vai ficar assim:

```
<input type="radio" name="tipo_pessoa" value="fisica" checked="<?php echo $checked1; ?>" />
Fisica

<input type="radio" name="tipo_pessoa" value="juridica" checked="<?php echo $checked2; ?>" />
Juridica
```

Comment: O navegador interpreta o mesmo resultado para os dois tipos de sintaxe .<input type="radio" checked="<?php echo $checked1; ?>" /> OR <input type="radio" checked /> Se existir alguma diferença, explique-me por gentileza

Comment: está apresentando mesmo problema de antes... ele fica com o checked sempre somente no juridica mesmo quando o user está como pessoa fisica

Answer (score 0):

Verifiquei que se você carregar a página pelo **F5** no **Firefox**, ele não obedece a regra estipulada, e sim deixa selecionado sempre o último(deve armazenar em cache). Mas se você recarregar com **ENTER** ou **CTRL+F5**, ele obedece a regra. Já no **Chrome**, funcionou normal.

Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
 <?php
        $row['tipo_pessoa'] = 'juridica';
        ?>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-lg-9'>
                <div class='radio'>
                    <label for='fisica'>
                        <input type="radio" name="tipo_pessoa" value="fisica" <?= ($row['tipo_pessoa'] == 'fisica') ? 'checked' : '' ?> />Fisica
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class='radio'>
                    <label for='juridica'>
                        <input type="radio" name="tipo_pessoa" value="juridica" <?= ($row['tipo_pessoa'] == 'juridica') ? 'checked' : ''  ?> />Juridica
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Minha sugestão: se continuar a persistir o "problema", faça a manipulação pelo **DOCUMENT**.